# How to make a div slide into place jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a `<div>` slide into the screen when a function is called.  At this moment, I have it so it will appear on the screen on click.  Anyone know how to make it slide in?  *would be a great plus if it could slide out also.

Javascript:

```
function show() {
    var website = document.getElementById('website');
    website.style.left = '0%';
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="show()" style="color:#999;">Superman - Wikipedia, the    free encyclopedia</a>
<div id="website">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#website {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #666;
    width: 100%;
    left: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/TLtqe/

It will slide in and also slide out.

```
$('a').on('click',function() {
    if($('#website').css('left')=='0px'){
        $('#website').animate({left: '-100%'}, 1000);        
    }else{
        $('#website').animate({left:0}, 1000); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a id="show" style="color:#999;">Superman - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#show').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#website').animate({
        left: 0
    }, 5000);
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yFLj3/)

Comment: Could you make this work with my href?  sorry, I'm new to Javascript.

Comment: Uhm, for me the div is not moving.  But yes, that is better.